# UML tool for creating diagramms with little clicks

Tags: ide, uml

Please, suggest adequately simple UML diagramming tool.

I don't want to be obliged to rightclick at the page, then select "Create Class/Entity", then work with class dialog, then right-click to add each attribute and to set it up with GUI...

The class symbol is just a rectangle and it's contents is just a text. So I would like to edit it so simple as text editing.

So, for example, I want to enter something like

```
BankAccount<ENTER><ENTER>
owner : String<ENTER>
balance : Dollars=0<ENTER><ENTER>
deposit(amount : Dollars)<ENTER>
withdrawl( amount : Dollars )<ENTER>
```

to get the following picture

[image]

So no excess clicks and keystokes, only what is absolutely necessary. No obliged dialogs and context menus.

This ability should not be just initial, i.e. once created class should remain editable. For example, to add attribute one should required to place cursor and previous attribute and press ENTER or some simple insert command.

Of course IF I WANT I should be able to call dialogs and property lists to fine tune my data.

The Visual Studio's Database editor can be regarded as good prototype.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this web tool, nice and user-friendly: http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/draw

Comment: This is one-way converter, i.e. I can't edit graphics visually, only source.

Comment: @SuzanCioc There is also a more powerful desktop version that should give you the graphic editing options as well: http://www.umlet.com/

Comment: @icepack how can we download that tool

Comment: @icepack for this we need to install java in our system. Thanks any way icepack thanks for your help.

Comment: @SuzanCioc may you should try altova for this...its a software for UML, XMLspy and many more...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18975/discussion-between-amitesh-and-icepack)

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of [textual UML modeling tools](http://modeling-languages.com/uml-tools/#textual) to choose from. Some of them only render the model but others like [textUML](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/textuml/index.php?title=TextUML_Toolkit) generate a fully compliant Ecore/XMI UML models that you can then open and edit with usual graphical tools